# Basic code that checks if a pixel matches a color made with pyautogui gives error when ran

Tags: python, pyautogui

I made a simple code that detects if a pixel matches color and its giving a error that I can't understand

code:

```
import pyautogui

running = True

while running == True:
    if pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(225, 579, (83, 83, 83), tolerance=5):
        pyautogui.press('space')
```

The editor doesn't give any errors until the code is ran

the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/utkuocal/Desktop/Python/BotTest2.py", line 6, in <module>
    if pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(225, 579, (83, 83, 83), tolerance=5):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 589, in pixelMatchesColor
    pix = pixel(x, y)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 618, in pixel
    return RGB(*(screenshot().getpixel((x, y))[:3]))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 477, in _screenshot_osx
    im = Image.open(tmpFilename)
NameError: name 'Image' is not defined
```

Also it somehow takes a screenshot every time it is ran
[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Aj5o.png)

OS: macOS 12.3 Monterey

IDE: VisualStudio Code

Python: 3.10.6

Comment: i do not get this error.

Comment: users need to be able to reproduce the answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
please check the question and verify you see this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the PIL (Python Image Library)

In the terminal type:

```py
pip install PIL
```

In your code:

```py
from PIL import Image
```